# UIWebView and timeouts

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, timeout, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm using a `UIWebView` to display some content. Within this content the user can navigate through a bunch of sites which are being loaded using AJAX. One step on this sites requires quite some time. Since I didn't find anything about a timeoue for `UIWebView` I tried to set it on the initial `NSURLRequest` it loads.

Unfortunately this does not seem to do anything. I'm not quite sure if I'm supposed to set the timeout myself? Is there anything I'm missing? Does the `UIWebView` override my timeout? I'm a little bit confused on this so any help would be appreciated. :)

Best
–f

**Update**

I built a test project to verify my "theory" on how the `UIWebView` works with timeouts. Here is the setup:

- a PHP file called sleep.php that has a parameter with which I can configure the time to sleep until it sends a result
- a little Xcode project with a single view which is a webView that loads the sleep.php like this:

  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:10];
  [webView loadRequest:request];

So, while playing with the seconds parameter I could see that the `UIWebView` works as it should. I get either `webViewDidFinishLoad:` or `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` depending on the timeout.

After verifying that the `timeoutInterval` works as advertised I brought in a proxy.php (that has two links to the sleep.php configured with 5 and 15 seconds) to see if my request configuration is still valid for new requests. I changed the initial `NSURLRequest` to use the proxy.php but left the 10 seconds configuration for the timeout.

When I start the app now the two links are being displayed. When I click the first one it loads as expected after 5 seconds. Unfortunately, the second link loads as well after 15 seconds.

So my first attempt to reconfigure the `NSURLRequest` would be to change it in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`. Unfortunately again, the web service works with AJAX so the delegate method does not get called.

Any other suggestions? Is there a way to globally configure the timeout value for the whole `UIWebView`?

Best
–f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the `UIWebView` does not use the same `NSURLRequest` over and over again. So my answer would be, that it's not possible to globally configure a timeout for the `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in watching the `UIWebView` delegate `webViewDidFinishLoading`  with your own custom `NSTimer`.

Also if you're having an issue till the server get you the response you can set the timeout for `NSURLConnection` **on** `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`

Comment: `webView:didFinishLoading:` does not seem to get called when working with AJAX requests on the server side, so this is not an option. And the other approach using `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:` is what I've already tried. Does the `UIWebView` use the same `NSURLRequest` for every new request that occurs or does it create new ones I can't manipulate?