# iOS timeout set up for webView loading?

Tags: ios, timeout

It might be simple question but I haven't found the clear answer.
I am loading a simple webview as following.. However, when signal is not good, it's just stuck there forever..

Could you please advise me the best way to set time out for this?

[TestViewController.webView loadRequest:requestObject]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the timeout for the NSURLRequest

```
NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:10]; // timeoutInterval is in seconds

[TestViewController.webView loadRequest:requestObject]
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788237/uiwebview-and-timeouts) SO post

Comment: of course I tried this before posting question.. But it still seems to be stuck there forever..

Answer (score 0):

> However, when signal is not good, it's just stuck there forever..

The default timeouts for NSURLConnection are pretty good, and should probably not be changed. What do you mean with 'stuck forever'. Are you checking for errors to see if your connection times out, so you can respond to this?

For example, did you implement the error delegate?

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

According to the Apple developer discussion mentioned in the post linked to by @ElJay if you use a http body the a minimum timeout of 240 seconds is enforced. Also the suggested timeout of @ElJay of 10 seconds is way to short for mobile networks. I would suggest to keep the default timeouts and try improve your error handling.

Comment: My bad.. webViewdidFailLoadWithError was not implemented.. Thanks :)